# Wrong path error message with pdf xchange editor after build and view

Tags: pdf, texniccenter

I have the following problem with my PDF viewer giving me errors when I want to build and view my Latex output directly. Weird thing is, that my configuration has worked in the past without issues. 
I'm using TexnicCenter with PDF-XChange Editor with the following configuration:
[image]

**Here comes the weird part:**

After the build, my PDF viewer is started, giving me three errormessages sequentially, first with only part of the path to the document, than mor of the path and only the last message has the full path:

*First Error Message:*

[image]

*Second Error Message:*

[image]

*Third Error Message:*

[image]

Anyone has an idea what is happening here and how to rectify it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely culprit is the Box Sync folder name has a space try rename to \BoxSync\ (without a space)

It may be possible to adjust the `%bm` to include "quotes" but first it may be worth trying

`%sbm.pdf`

This changes the behaviour to the older Short 8.3 method of passing files. There is a really long list of alternatives to %bm in the manual however none say handle spaces.

It is up to you to try `"%bm.pdf"` which may or may not always work hence my suggestion to first try  %sbm.pdf which "should" be more robust but not all pdf viewers may agree.

More details at http://texniccenter.sourceforge.net/placeholders.html

Comment: Thank you, a short change of the path to another place showed that your answer is correct. Since I don't think it is good to synchonice after each build with the cloud anyway I just move my working folder elsewhere. 
Thanks again, you just saved me a lot of grief :)